# How to pass subject value to switchMap inside the pipe?

Tags: rxjs

I have a below behavior subject state and i was stored studentNo value from some other component,

```
const initialState: any = {
   studentNo: '',
}
private _state$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(initialState);
get state$(): Observable<any> { return this._state$; }

private _requestStudent$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
```

and then i listening the `this.requestStudent$` subject inside the service file constructor block,

```
constructor(): void {
   this._requestStudent$.pipe(
      tap(this.state$),//Is this correct way to pass state$ value to below switchMap?,
      switchMap(this.requestStudentDetail.bind(this)),
   ).subscribe(this._studentList$);
}

requestStudentDetail(state: any): Observable<any> {
   return this.http....// I got the undefined value, If i print state.studentNo value here
}

public getStundentDetail(): void {// i called this function from component A
   this._requestStudent$.next();
}
```

How can i pass the state value(studentNo) to the http api service function without subscribe `this.state$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use 'withLatestFrom' rxjs operators to get the value from the subject, so i can re-write the code like below,

```
this._requestStudent$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.state$),
  switchMap(this.requestStudentDetail.bind(this)),
).subscribe(this._studentList$);
```

A.withLatestFrom(B) to get the value from observable B when observable A emits, like array [a, b] format.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might want to `switchMap` state first?

```
this._requestStudent$.pipe(
  switchMap(this.state$),
  switchMap((studentNumber) => this.requestStudentDetail(studentNumber)),
).subscribe(this._studentList$);
```

Comment: but this switchMap continuously calling if this state$ changed, so i used this.this.state$.pipe(first()) but next time not able to getting updated value.